# Can Azure Traffic Manager be used with API Management?

Tags: azure

When I add an endpoint to Traffic Manager only websites and cloud services are available to choose. Can I combine API Management services with Traffic Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, external endpoints can be added to an Azure Traffic Manager profile, beyond Azure Websites and Azure Cloud Services. You will need to use the Azure PowerShell module to set the custom endpoints.

1. Install the Azure PowerShell module: https://github.com/azure/azure-powershell/releases
2. Run the script below (replace `$Username` variable with your own account name)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/

```
### Authenticate to Azure from PowerShell
$Username = 'posh@trevorsullivan.net';
$AzureCredential = Get-Credential -Credential $Username;
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $AzureCredential;

### Select the appropriate Azure subscription, if you have multiple
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN';

### Retrieve the Traffic Manager profile (if already created)
$TrafficManagerProfile = Get-AzureTrafficManagerProfile -Name trevor;

### Add custom endpoints to the Traffic Manager Profile
Add-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint -TrafficManagerProfile $TrafficManagerProfile -DomainName www.microsoft.com -Type Any -Status Enabled;
Add-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint -TrafficManagerProfile $TrafficManagerProfile -DomainName trevorsullivan.net -Type Any -Status Enabled;

### Commit the changes to your Azure Traffic Manager Profile
Set-AzureTrafficManagerProfile -TrafficManagerProfile $TrafficManagerProfile;
```

It doesn't quite match the code above, but here's a screenshot of what my Traffic Manger profile named "Trevor" looks like, along with its two endpoints.

[image: Traffic Manager Profile]

Comment: Is it possible to have mysite.com/get and mysite.com/set go to different domains?